# Certificate Invalid after purchasing it on Azure

Tags: azure, ssl

I purchased a SSL certificate on the azure portal, configured it and got it to a "Ready" state. Then I imported it to one of my apps and connected to my domain vie https.

The result was this message window:

```
Invalid Certificate
```

I tried to add the binding for the domain in the azure portal. But here I get the warning message:

```
No certificates match the selected hostname
```

What am I missing? How do I solve this?

Comment: Is your app really using the certificate? According to the error message the domain name doesn't match CN (or alternative name) of the certificate

Comment: No certificate usually. It's the first time we're adding it to our app. Are you saying that the name of the certificate should be identical to the name of the domain? What if I need to use the same certificate for several apps on my domain? (i.e. app1.domain.com, app2.domain.com, etc.)

Comment: It's one of the security measures. The common name (cn) must equal the domain name. If you'd like to cover multiple domain with a single certificate, you may use [wildcard certificate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) or [Subject Alternative Name](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name)